# Looking for an ActionScript library for server-side JSON-RPC

Tags: json, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, json-rpc

I'm planning to integrate RPC via JSON-RPC in my Flex applications. I've searched around the net and already found librarys for calling remote methods, but I also need to offer methods myself. None of the libs I found seemed to have this functionality.
Are there any ActionScript librarys out there which let met offer methods via JSON-RPC?

Kind regards,
Markus

Comment: Generally; ActionScript / Flex are used as client side tools.  I would not recommend that you use ActionScript to implement anything server side, such as a services layer.  In theory it is possible with the use of socket's and Adobe AIR; but I'm not sure the time/effort it takes to build your own application server will outweigh the benefits of having complete control of your server side tech.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree with you. Actually, I'm working on a client application which connects to a server (native application, no Flash). The client is offering methods to be called by the server, so when looking for a library for server-side JSON-RPC I was talking about "server" in respect of the JSON-RPC 2.0 specification (the "server" being any program which offers methods to be called by a remote site).

Comment: In that case; I do not understand what information you are are after. There are plenty of libraries that Flex can use to communicate with a server.  You said you found some already.  Perhaps you should tell us what libraries you found and why the are insufficient for your needs.

Comment: Libaries I found include as3-rpclib (http://code.google.com/p/as3-rpclib) and an implementation which seems to have no name (http://json-rpc.org/browser/trunk/actionscript-jsonrpc). However, they both do not implement JSON-RPC 2.0 but an earlier version and both just let me call methods on a remote machine, not offer methods myself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "offer methods myself".  It sounds like you want to create your own API that others can call.  If so; then I refer back to my original comment about not using ActionScript to create a server.

Comment: That's correct, although I wouldn't call this application a server. I really appreciate that you're trying to point out possible problems, but nevertheless that's what I got to do.
As I couldn't find a ready-to-use library I ended up writing my own.
Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using playerGlobal version 10 or above than it is automatically incuded and you can directly call JSON.encode or JSON.decode methods. for PlayerGlobal version below 10, you can look for AS3CoreLib.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, encoding and decoding JSON is not a problem itself. My question aims at using the JSON-RPC protocol as described in http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification